# How do we test if an model or algorithm is AI-complete?

Tags: agi, intelligence-testing, turing-test, ai-completeness

How do we test if a model or algorithm is [AI-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete), a problem is said to be AI-complete if it requires generalized, human-level intelligence, that is, requires strong AI. The Turing test and its variants are the best ways we have of measuring this. See, for example, [Turing Test as a Defining Feature of AI-Completeness](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-29694-9_1).

As suggested in [this paper](http://wizzion.com/papers/2012/AISB-TuringTestTaxonomy.pdf#page=54), in order for the Turing test to be meaningful, the interrogator has a responsibility to ask questions which are both deep and meaningful.

It, therefore, seems likely that testing for strong AI is in itself an AI-complete task.